# .NET Core - use custom domains locally (vs or through cli)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have dot net Core 1 solution made up of various projects
- webapi
- mvc web app 1
- mvc web app 2 (running Angular SPA)
- mvc web app 3 (running Angular SPA)

all runnning of Core 1. (this is on Win 10)

I'm building a PoC for a multi-tenant system which requires single-sign-on.

I need to be able to run each of the above locally (IISExpress or Kestrel) using custom domains to mirror how this would be in production:
e.g.

```
dev.my-api.com
dev.client-app1.com
dev.client-app2.com
dev.client-app3.com
```

I've tweaked hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.my-api.com
127.0.0.1 dev.client-app1.com
127.0.0.1 dev.client-app2.com
127.0.0.1 dev.client-app3.com
```

And also the applicationhost.config - found in .vs\config of the solution.

Each project in the solution has binding like:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:dev.my-api.com" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50100:localhost" />

<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:dev.client-app1.com" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50200:localhost" />

<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:dev.client-app2.com" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50300:localhost" />
```

the launchsettings.json is also updated with relevant custom domain.

But, I just cannot get all the apps running simultaneously withouth dotnet.exe blowing up or getting strange 404 errors.

If I try using kestrel and set the "launchUrl" in launchsettings.json for each proej, then try cli - dotnet restore, dotnet run it blows up with stackoverflow exception.

Anyone got any pointers on how best to achieve this sort of thing in a dotnet Core solution with multiple projects running locally?